# ColdFusion cfmail special characters in subject line

Tags: unicode, coldfusion, coldfusion-9, cfmail

Special characters in the subject line of the mail getting converted in to question marks or boxes.

I have tried to wrap the dynamic string of the subject line in URLEncodedFormat , however ended up in vain.

```
<cfset strSubject= URLEncodedFormat(s)>
<cfmail 
  from="xxxxx@xx.com" 
  to="yyyyyyy@yyy.com" 
  subject="#strSubject#"         
  type="html"
>
  #testText#
</cfmail>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Assuming the special characters are unicode charactes, you will have to encode the string to a base64 format and use that in the subject line. Like this,

```
<cfset strSubject="Demande d’chantillons supplémentaires">
<cfset strSubject=ToBase64(strSubject, "utf-8")>

<cfmail from="test@test.com" to="test@test.com" subject="=?utf-8?B?#strSubject#?=" type="html">
    #testText#
</cfmail>
```

The subject line must be in the format `=?<charset>?<encoding>?<encoded text>?=`

The `?` and `=` are required.

[MIME - Encoded Word](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME#Encoded-Word)

> "**charset**" may be any character set registered with IANA. Typically
>   it would be the same charset as the message body.
>
> "**encoding**" can be either "Q" denoting Q-encoding that is similar
>   to the quoted-printable encoding, or "B" denoting base64 encoding.
>
> "**encoded text**" is the Q-encoded or base64-encoded text.

Comment: Cool Solution. Here is wiki entry explaining this http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME#Encoded-Word

Answer (score 0):

Also: add charset="utf-8" to the cfmail tag. If you are using utf-8 in the subject, you will probably also use it in the body.