# ColdFusion text symbols in subject line

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9, cfmail

Hi I would like to put one of the text symbols from http://fsymbols.com/all/ website into my 
coldfusion cfmail subject line, How can I do this? I followed the instruction from this post [ColdFusion cfmail special characters in subject line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9374948/coldfusion-cfmail-special-characters-in-subject-line) and doesn't works for I guess these symbols? I am using scissor ✂ symbol and it gets converted to âœ when I get the email

Please suggest or help.

```
    <cfset strSubject="✂#qrynotify.EmailSubject#">
    <cfset strSubject=ToBase64(strSubject, "utf-8")>         

    <cfmail from="test@tesy.com" to="#qrynotify.Email#" 
            subject="=?utf-8?B?#strSubject#?=" 
            server="localhost" type="html" charset="utf-8">#qrynotify.EmailContent#</cfmail>
```

Comment: Well, I am subscribed to orbitz and I get emails with these kinda fonts. For e.g Subject: ✈ Flights on sale from $114 round-trip ✈

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood what the website was doing; just removed that comment, but I guess not quick enough. :)

Comment: You have to isolate the problem.  It may be the email client that's the culprit.  If this were my problem, the first thing I would try is to put a textarea right after each cfset and have #strSubject# as the value attribute.  I'd be looking to see if I got my scissor symbol.  I don't know if it would work, but I think it's worth a shot.

Comment: If the email client was at fault, the OP wouldn't receive the orbitz emails correctly? The issue is either server-side (CF or mail server), or possibly the editor used to write the code. First step would be to to check the encoding for each of these is set to appropriate values. Also, might need [cfprocessingdirective](http://cfdocs.org/cfprocessingdirective) here.

Comment: I am literally putting the scissor symbol in the subject line as is the symbol is not getting submitted from the textarea.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you guys for all your effort, I was able to resolve this issue.

```
    <cfprocessingdirective pageEncoding="utf-8"> 
    <cfmail from="test@tesy.com" to="#qrynotify.Email#" 
                subject="✂#qrynotify.EmailSubject#" 
                server="localhost" type="html" charset="utf-8">#qrynotify.EmailContent#</cfmail>
```

I placed the scissor symbol directly into the subject attribute instead of settings it in the variable and letting ColdFusion evaluate. I also added cfprocessingdirective that Peter suggested.

Thanks

Comment: I was thinking it was the editor you were using.  I copied the sample ColdFusion code from your question and then copied the special characters from your post and it worked fine using ColdFusion Builder.  Anyway, glad you got it working.